# Mod_rewrite: Is it possible to ignore existing directories by default?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem with my new server.

There is a rule the server ignores by default if there is an existing directory with that name. If no directory exists, everything works.

There is no RewriteCond on it...

Is there a server option for that?

On the old server the same code worked fine!

thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `MultiViews` option enabled? If so, disable it. A similar question lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/53203071

Comment: @hjpotter92: Thank you. But that wasnt the solution. For example: If i try to Open www.xyz.de/ , the rule says go to about.php. The Server finds an index.php and opens this instead. But I dont want this...

Comment: Can you show us your existing RewriteRules, RewriteConds, etc?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /about.php [L]